# Override function that return base type

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have two classes. Base class `Parent` and derived class `Child`. Class `Parent` has pure virtual function that returns its class type. How can I override it in derived class?

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        virtual Parent* OverrideMe(Parent* func) = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        Child* OverrideMe(Child* func) override;
};
```

I tried `Child* OverrideMe(Child* func) override;` but I end up with error that it does not override a base class member.

Comment: Although C++ does not support it, contravariance would require a parameter that is less specific than `Parent*`, not more specific. The point is that you can use `Parent` and not know about `Child`. Passing a `Parent*` that is not a `Child*` would break things.

Comment: Your design is wrong. It should be `virtual Parent* OverrideMe(Child* func) = 0; (with a forward to Child). Still, it is ugly. You may make Parent and Child derived from some Node  (avoiding the inheritance from Parent to Child).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If C++ had full covariance and contravariance support, the correct relationship would be **contravariant** in input and **covariant** in output. Namely:

```
struct Organism { };

struct Animal : Organism {
    virtual Animal* OverrideMe(Animal* ) = 0;
};

struct Dog : Aniaml {
    Dog* OverrideMe(Organism* ) override { ... }
    ↑↑↑             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    covariant       contravariant
};
```

It seems a little unintuitive, but it does make sense. If you are expecting a `Animal*`, you should be able to handle anything that is a `Animal*` (of which a `Dog*` qualifies). Conversely, if you are doing some operation on a `Animal*`, you just need an operation that can take a `Animal*` - and an operation that takes an `Organism*` qualifies on that front.

Note that if the input was **co**variant, that would break the type system. Consider something like;

```
Animal* a = new Dog;
a->OverrideMe(new Cat);
```

If `Dog::OverrideMe` were allowed to take a `Dog*`, that would fail - a `Cat*` is not a `Dog*`! So it is allowed to take an `Animal*` ... or anything more generic than that (e.g. `Organism*`), since all of those work fine.

C++ does **not** have support for contravariance in input, only **covariance** in output. So you could write either:

```
Dog* OverrideMe(Animal* ) override { ... }
```

or:

```
Animal* OverrideMe(Animal* ) override { .... }
```

but nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the function parameter and the function's cv qualifiers have to be the same. So you can use

```
Child* OverrideMe(Parent* func) override;
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't overriding here because your `OverrideMe` function doesn't take in the same arguments as the function in the base class you are trying to override:

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        virtual Parent* OverrideMe(Parent* func) = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        virtual Child* OverrideMe(Parent* func) override;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This "smells bad", in other words, you are "breaking" the normal "any object should be replaceable with any other object that is derived from it".

If you have an interface function in the base-class, then the function should take the same type throughout the class hierarchy.

So the correct thing is to:

Parent* OverrideMe(Parent* func) override;

(You could, as juanchopanza says, return a derived type, but are you sure that the parent returned value will ALWAYS be the same class? To me, this looks like the type of function that could potentially return "any derived object", in which case you'd either be lying or end up with "Interesting effects")

If for some reason this doesn't actually "work" in your case, then you probably shouldn't be using inheritance in this way.